# FormAuthentication Ticket expiration check

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, session-timeout

I have a asp.net application where i am using FormAuthentication Ticket when user Sign in....on each page I want to check if FormAuthentication Ticket has expired.

Actually i have two scenarios

1. I want to check if user is authenticated or trying to access the page directly without signing in (in this case i want to redirect on "Default.aspx"
2. If user is already signed and authenticated but the timeout occured (in this case i want to redirect to the page "sexpired.aspx" where user will be notified "your session has expired please sign in again" with the link to "Default.aspx" and it would redirect back to the return url. Please advise and suggest solutions accordingly.

Currently i am doing this on every page and I think when cookie expires it makes `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false` also cause on timeout when user tries to load the page it redirects back to "Default.aspx"

Okay here is my updated question with login form code behind:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (AuthenticateUser("SPOINT", txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
   {
        //Fetch the role
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

        //Create Command object
        DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Users");

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@userid", System.Data.DbType.String, 20);
        db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@userid", txtUsername.Text);

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@fname", System.Data.DbType.String, 80);
        db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@fname", null);

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@lname", System.Data.DbType.String, 80);
        db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@lname", null);

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@phone", System.Data.DbType.String, 50);
        db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@phone", null);

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@mobile", System.Data.DbType.String, 50);
        db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@mobile", null);

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@email", System.Data.DbType.String, 100);
        db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@email", null);

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@uroleids", System.Data.DbType.String, 50);
        db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@uroleids", null);

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@uroles", System.Data.DbType.String, 500);
        db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@uroles", null);

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@umenu", System.Data.DbType.Int16);
        db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@umenu", null);

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@ustatus", System.Data.DbType.String, 1);
        db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@ustatus", null);

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@reqType", System.Data.DbType.String, 1);
        db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@reqType", "R");

        db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "@retval", DbType.Int16, 2);

        IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(cmd);

        System.Collections.ArrayList roleList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            roleList.Add(reader[0]);
            string myRoles = (string)roleList[0];
            //Read user name
            string uname = (string)reader[1];
            //Read User menu ID
            int menuID = Convert.ToInt16(reader[2]);

            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUsername.Text, DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), true, myRoles, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

            //Read user full name in session variable which will be shared across the whole application
            Session["uid"] = txtUsername.Text;
            Session["ufullname"] = uname; //myname; //uname;
            Session["branch"] = 1;

            //For security reasons we may hash the cookies
            string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);

            // add the cookie to user browser
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            //Constructing Menu according to User Role
            string x = buildmenu(menuID);

            Globals.menuString = null;
            Globals.menuString = x;

            string returnURL = "~/Main.aspx";

            //Close reader object to avoid Connection Pooling troubles
            reader.Close();

            if (Request.QueryString["rUrl"] != null)
                Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["rUrl"]);
            else
                Response.Redirect(returnURL);
        }
        else
        {
            //Validation Error here...
            lblError.Text = "Incorrect UserID/Password entered...";
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblError.Text = "Incorrect UserID/Password entered...";
        return;
   }
}
```

Here is my code behind where i am checking formauthentication ticket

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Maker"))
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your login/auth code it is hard to determine how you have things setup.

The first thing you should probably do, is set the session/cookie timeout to be session expire time + 1 minute (eg 21 minutes)

Then you can either write a `HttpModule` to check the timeout and redirect

```
public class ExpireModule : IHttpModule {

    public virtual void Init(HttpApplication app) {
        app.PostAuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(app_PostAuthenticateRequest);
    }

    private void app_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //check ticket
        //if old, kill login, redirect to session timeout page
    }
}
```

Or do the same thing in a shared base page (if you have one)

By making the session timeout 21 minutes, you can use all the standard auth code

Comment: I have edited my question and pasted the full code for formauthentication on login button. Guys plz respond I would really appreciate.

Comment: the second section of code (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated), where you check the ticekt, where is that?

Comment: I dont check the ticket once user has authenticated the current.user.Identity.IsAuthenticated gets the updated value for the session NO? or do i need to check the ticket explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

To set default page to be opened when user is not authorized, set `loginUrl`.

Also don't forget to check that `slidingExpiration` is not set to `false`!

```
<forms
    name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
    loginUrl="Default.aspx"
    defaultUrl="Default.aspx"
    slidingExpiration="true"
    timeout="30" />
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx)

---

To check does timeout came to the end, use Global.asax event `Application_BeginRequest`:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{   
    protected virtual void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!his.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            this.Response.Redirect("Timeout.aspx");
    }    
}
```